Problem connecting to a mySql database in a java project
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to connect to my database created on HeidiSQL. Specifically, I'm receiving the following error message:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbname.
Below, I've included the section of code causing the error and my Gradle file, which I use to manage dependencies.
package utilities;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnectionUtil {
    // Imposta i dettagli della connessione al tuo database
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbname";
    private static final String USERNAME = "myUsername";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "myPassword";
    private static final String DRIVER = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";

    // Metodo statico per ottenere una nuova connessione al database
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    }
}


build.gradle.kts
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details on building Java & JVM projects,
 * please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/building_java_projects.html in the Gradle documentation.
 */

plugins {
    application
    java
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    id("java-library")
}


repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.3.3")
    implementation ("com.github.lgooddatepicker:LGoodDatePicker:11.2.1")
    testImplementation(libs.junit.jupiter)
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = "myLauncher"
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

I've searched online for potential solutions and found suggestions such as including Class.forName(org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver). However, not only is this no longer necessary, but it also triggers the error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.
I've also considered the possibility that Gradle might not be including the libraries correctly. However, the other libraries I'm using are functioning properly, so that doesn't seem to be the issue either.
Also, when I run the build in the terminal, there are no errors indicating that the library couldn't be found on Maven.
Could you please review the provided information and suggest any necessary corrections or solutions?
Thank you.

so ... did you actually provide that driver?

Show your module-info file.

Let's be clear: is your DB MySql or MariaDB?

If the latter, then you want private static final String URL = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mydbname"; and yes, get rid of the Class.forName stuff.

@g00seit keeps giving me this error java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mydb.
Is a DB created on HeidiSQL that accept both mysql and mariadb connections.

@Stultuske It ought to reside within the library that I include in the Gradle file using this dependency: implementation("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.3.3").

@SedJ601 I do not have a module-info file in my project, is that a mistake?

afaics, HeidiSql is a Windows-only program that allows you to connect to existing servers. So again, is your existing server MariaDB or MySql?

@g00se is a MariaDB server

@g00se Alright, I found the error. There was an issue with the classpath of my project; it seems the library wasn't being read for some reason. I tried recreating the project, and now it's working. Thank you anyway because the error you found in the URL was correct. Have a great day!

Good, but I don't quite know how you had a classpath problem if you have a Gradle project

By the way, Class.forName and DriverManager have not been needed for many years. In modern Java, JDBC drivers are automatically registered via Java Service Provider Interface (SPI).

@g00se When I initially created the project, VS Code presented me with a warning regarding the classpath, and I clicked 'Yes' without verifying. This likely caused the issue.

As you can read on https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#jdbcmysql-scheme-compatibility, MariaDB Connector/J 3.0 and newer only accept the jdbc:mariadb: scheme by default, so that if you have MariaDB Connector/J and MySQL Connector/J both present, each is selected appropriately.
You can ass ?permitMysqlScheme to the URL to make MariaDB Connector/J handle the jdbc:mysql: scheme or instead use the jdbc:mariadb: scheme.
That the Class.forName is not working is a sign that somehow your classpath is not correct and does not MariaDB Connector/J JAR. But also it is not necessary anymore since many years.
